# Архитектура приложения ?

Tags: mvc, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Надо написать приложение которое будет визуализатором нескольких алгоритмов сортировки и поиска. Соответвенно планирую использовать паттерн MVC. Не могу придумать как правильно построить логику..

Comment: Так а в чем, собственно, вопрос? - сейчас это больше похоже на дневниковую запись.

Comment: :) вопрос как организовать логику, то есть я думаю представление сделать на основе JTable, соответственно модель будет экстендить AbstractTableModel.. 
Не могу понять как я должен построить модель (наверное их должно быть несколько - для каждого алгоритма ?) и контроллер для каждой модели ?

Comment: Что собираетесь визуализировать ? Откуда данные получать ? Откуда собираетесь брать данные для сортировок и поисков ? Приложение интерактивное или нет ? Графическое ? Web ?

Обстоятельно ответьте себе на эти вопросы и архитектура сама нарисуется.

--

Подозреваю, что на самом деле все просто, как палка и веревка. 

В цикле выбираете номер алгоритма и м.б. несколько параметров его запуска. Генерите данные (в файле или массиве, зависиит от ...(места мало)). Меряете время, память и т.п. Выводите их.

Конец цикла.

Вот и вся логика (и никаких тут модных паттернов).

Comment: @avp отвечу вам на вопросы) визуализировать буду алгоритмы сортировки( я думаю не важно какие) и поиска по, скажем, двоичному дереву. Данные в общем случае в простом текстовом файле. Приложение графическое и интерактивное (на Java Swing).
Ну цикл я думаю слишком просто..

Comment: визуализировать буду алгоритмы сортировки - даже не могу представить, что имеется ввиду.

Comment: @dword никогда не видили визуализаторы алгоритмов?

Comment: Нет, не доводилось.

Comment: вот посмотрите, например rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/vis
там есть раздел и алгоритмов сортировки

Comment: @pol, а как Вашей ссылкой пользоваться ? В смысле я зашел, нашел список визуализаторов, ткунлся в какой-то про сорировку и мне высветили форму, что-то про архив и т.п.

Вы толком объясните, как это чудо смотреть или что мы должны видеть...

Comment: Не могу писать комментов к вопросу)

@avp ну например заходите на [quick sort][1] там java applet загрузиться, я думаю дальше там очевидно..


  [1]: http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/vis/sorts/quicksort-2004

Comment: Пардон, третья попытка (*очередь поиска в ширину*) удалась. Там появилось окошко с квадратиками и линиями между ними. Я кликнул **[Авто]** и квадратики стали менять цвет, а линии становиться стрелочками и тоже цвет меняли.

Честно, не знаю, как из произвольной программы, реализующей алгоритм, нужные данные в процессе ее работы извлечь. Наверное автор рисования картинки сам ее (реализацию алгоритма) так пишет, что она в определенных точках нужные методы вызывает.

Но это предположение, конечно.

И еще, подобный взгляд (изображение) на вычислительный процесс IMHO крайне индивидуален.

Comment: @avp не очень понял, что вам непонятно/непонравилось. Подобные визуализаторы используются при изучении алгоритмов - очень наглядно. Какие данные вы хотите извлекать тоже непонятно...

Comment: @pol, я вот что не понял. Вы сделали ответ с ссылкой на quick sort. 

Я туда зашел, посмотрел. Написал обстоятельный комментарий что здорово и как через java интерфейс, который вызывается из quicsort с последующей его реализацией это можно изображать.

Но (!), пока я смотрел-писал  вопрос превратился в комментарий (здесь, он отсылает на quick sort), а мой комментарий пропал. 

Подозреваю, что эта непонятка относится не к Вам, @pol, а к ошибкам в реализации сайта ХэшКод.

Comment: или модераторам =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не знаете как решить какую-то задачу разделите ее на составляющие. Я например, когда разбирался с разными алгоритмами все операции (сравнение, перестановку, обращение и запись элеметов) выносил в отдельные методы посему легко было добавить счетчики, которые потом успешно выводились в консоль.

Если к этому простому решению добавить шаблон **обсервер** то вместо того чтоб обновлять счетчики для каждой произведенной операции можно отсылать уведомления всем прослушивателям. В вашем случае последними будет элементы GUI интерфейса, в коде это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
interface ActionListener
{
   void handle(Object event);
}

abstract class ASorter
{
    public enum ActionType {READ, WRITE,COMPARE}

    private Map<ActionType, List<ActionListener>> listeners = null;

    public void addListener(ActionType t, ActionListener l) {...};

    public void abstract sort (int [] array);

    // далее идет набор воспомагательных методов используемых при сортировке
    // также они будут отсылать уведомление всем слушателям 
    protected void notifyListeners(ActionType type, Object event)
    {
         foreach (ActionListener l : listeners.get(type))
         {
            l.handle(event);
         }     
    }

    public void set(int [] array, int index, int value)
    {
         //  выполняем непосредственно действие
         array[index] = value;

         // отсылаем уведомление
         Object e = new Object();

         notifyListeners(ActionType.WRITE, e);
    }

     ...
}
```

в качестве листенеров будут выступать ваши компоненты, напр:

class DisplaySort extends JFrame implements ActionListener {...}

все что вам надо это добавить все необходимые enum константы и реализовать все необходимые методы для этих инвентов (read, write, или просто swap, compare, и другие)

в данном примере в качестве event используется просто Object но вам никто не мешает использовать для этого какой-то свой специальный класс с необходимым функционалом

думаю понятно что для того чтоб это работало надо для реализации алгоритма использовать воспомагательные методы реализованные в классе ASorter (set,get,compare, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае я бы сделал так: на каждый алгоритм по своей модели с унифицированным интерфейсом - это позволит обойтись одним контроллером, который в зависимости от входных данных будет обращаться к нужной модели.

п.с. MVC это скорее парадигма нежели паттерн.

Comment: MVC скорее все же паттерн =)

Answer (score 0):

[@avp](/users/232/avp) мой ответ превратился в комментарий благодаря пользователю у которого на это достатчно прав)) Этот ответ может тоже превратиться в комментарий))

Тем не менее я реально в затруднении реализации подобного визуализатора - данные представлять логичнее всего в таблице, а стандартный JTable имеет свою модель и свои алгоритмы сортировки и тд..

Comment: ты топчешься на месте, сядь, создай проект, напиши код своих алгоритмов сортировки, выведи данные на консоль, напиши таблицу, если так уж хочешь, напиши для нее модель, выведи в нее данные